# Devexpress ASPxDateEdit control OnDateChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, devexpress

Below is my Markup page code of the ASPxDateEdit control:

```
    <dx:ASPxDateEdit 
    ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" Width="100px" EditFormat="Date"
    AllowNull="true" EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" MinDate="01-Jan-0001" OnDateChanged="txtDateTime_DateChanged"/>
```

And Here is the code behind of handling the OnDateChanged event

```
  protected void txtDateTime_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code on handling onDateChanged event
}
```

My problem is that the OnDateChanged event isn't firing, why this case happens?

---

I solved this problem yesterday, thanks for everyone's help
Answer:
What I want to do is a client side event, but what I did is a server side event, so I solved this problem by putting a "AutoPostBack="True"" to it

Comment: Why don't you try to handle the `EditValueChanged` event ?

Comment: We need more info. Is it doing a postback or a callback? Have you placed a breakpoint to see if the code is reached but nothing happens on the clientside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a postback you are trying to achieve set the ASPxDateEdit.AutoPostBack true. The ASPxDateEdit does not postback data automatically.

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit 
ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" Width="100px" EditFormat="Date"
AllowNull="true" EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" MinDate="01-Jan-0001" 

AutoPostBack="True"

OnDateChanged="txtDateTime_DateChanged"/>
```

If it is a callback (from a callback panel) then you might be trying to change things outside the callback panel, which won't happen as the callback is essentialy an ajax call.

For more info look [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxDateEdit_DateChangedtopic). It states that the Event is dependent on the AutoPostBack property.